# Nodejs Kinesis Client fails with not much clue

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, producer

i am writing a simple nodejs kinesis producer client which fails with no helpful information. Here's the code:

```
const { Kinesis, PutRecordsCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-kinesis");

const kinesis_client = new Kinesis({
    region: 'us-east-1'
});

/**
 * 
 * @param {*} streamName 
 */
async function kinesis_pushdata() {

    const params = {
        StreamName: "course-progress",
        Records: [
        {
            Data: JSON.stringify({
            'record' : 'sample record'
            }),
            ParitionKey: 1
        }
        ]
    };

    try {
        const data = await kinesis_client.send(new PutRecordsCommand(params));
        console.log(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
      
}

kinesis_pushdata();
```

Credentials are configured to be picked up from the config file. When i run this, i get a TypeError " TypeError: Cannot read property 'byteLength' of undefined " with not much clue on what's happening.

Any pointers will be very helpful.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Kinesis expecting Data in following form

```
{
...
 {
  Data: Buffer.from( JSON.stringify({...}) )
 }
}
```

Check the AWS document [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Kinesis.html#putRecord-property)